# Javascript ajax don't work

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I can't get this javascript code working.
I get the value from the option but it doesn't process trough ajax!

```
function get_lan() {
      var lan_code = document.getElementById('customDropdown1').value;
      var params = "lan=" + lan_code;
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/get_lan.php",
            data: params,
            success: function(result) { 
                callback(result);
                document.getElementById("lan_code").innerHTML = result;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are there any errors getting the page?

Comment: Is callback defined ? Do you have an error in the console ? Did you at least debug with a breakpoint at the start of the success function ?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong, are you getting any errors? What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 zepto.js:73
Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined

Comment: If a separate callback function isn't needed, simply remove the line; otherwise it'll need to be defined.

Comment: @LinusOdenring: That's one error, or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `callback` is not defined and second you also need to call `get_lan() function` to get it work

Updated code

```
function get_lan() {
    var lan_code = document.getElementById('customDropdown1').value;
    var params = "lan=" + lan_code;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/get_lan.php",
        data: params,
        success: function(result) {
            document.getElementById("lan_code").innerHTML = result;
        }
    });
}

get_lan();
```